# unpickling stack underflow

Tags: python, pickle

I want to process a RRF file, but when I want to use pickle to process it, the error happens:

```
unpickling stack underflow
```

This is my code

```py
import pickle
f = open("MRCONSO.RRF",'rb')


db = pickle.load(f)
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

RRF is from NCI (National Clinical Institute). This file is one part of United Medical Library System.

Comment: Does your pickle file contain valid pickle data?

Comment: I am not sure, it is a RRF file. If not, what is the right way for me to process it?

Comment: What program created the RRF file? And is it RRF or RFF?

Comment: It is RRF. it is from NCI (National Clinical Institute). This file is one part of United Medical Library System